# Unwanted vertical spacing produced by DispWithArrows environment

Tags: witharrows

I'm trying to get familiar with the `witharrows` package, but i repeadtedly encounter unwanted vertical spacings produced by the  `DispWithArrow` environment.

## Example 1

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-10]
\begin{DispWithArrows}
    x &= (a + b)^2 \Arrow{expand}\\
    x &= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{DispWithArrows}
\lipsum[1][1-10]

\end{document}
```

Example 1 produces a document with extra vertical spacings between the lines of the first paragraph.

#### Output of Example 1

[image]

## Example 2

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]\par
\begin{DispWithArrows}
    x &= (a + b)^2 \Arrow{expand}\\
    x &= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{DispWithArrows}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}
```

My first thought was that there is a missing `\par` in example 1. Unfortunately terminating the line before the beginning of `DisplayWithArrows` with `\par` leads me to a new problem.

Although the additional vertical line spacing in the first paragraph is not shown in the compiled document anylonger, a new unwanted vertical spacing appears between the paragraph and the first line of the equation.

#### Output of Example 2

[image]

## Workaround

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]\par\vskip -\baselineskip
\begin{DispWithArrows}
    x &= (a + b)^2 \Arrow{expand}\\
    x &= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{DispWithArrows}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}
```

As a workaround i found that the extra vertical spacing is eliminated if i apply `\vskip -\baselineskip` after `\par`:

#### Output of Workaround

[image]

### Objectives

It would be great to know if anybody can reproduce the output of my examples and if there is a better way to solve the problem with regard to my workaround.

Comment: Clearly, this a bug of `witharrows`. I will try to solve it (I'm the author of `witharrows`).

Comment: @F.Pantigny  thanks for looking into my post and the great package you've developed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `nicematrix`. I have just uploaded on CTAN a new version (2.4, 2020-03-31) which solves that problem. This new version should be available in TeXLive and MikTeX within the next few days.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-10]
\begin{DispWithArrows}
    x &= (a + b)^2 \Arrow{expand}\\
    x &= a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\end{DispWithArrows}
\lipsum[1][1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Wow! That was fast. Thank you for tracking the bug down.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to solve your problem – maybe it is a bug. I propose a workaround,  using the `\ArrowBetweenLines(*)` command from `mathtools` and a similar arrow from `MnSymbol`:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-10]
\begin{alignat}{2}
    x &= (a + b)^2 & & \\[-1ex]
\ArrowBetweenLines*[\lcurvearrowdown\text{\small expand}]
    x &= a^2 + 2ab + b^2 & &
\end{alignat}
\lipsum[1][1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing your approach!